# Laravel How to add an interger value into an column once the user click follow or unfollow

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-8

could anyone help me. I'm making a follow system. My code is working but I want the integer value going into the follower column in users.  Is a `pivot` appropriate to use or is there something else I could use? Here's my code:

```
user model  
public function followers()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(User::class, 'followers', 'leader_id', 'follower_id');
}
public function followings()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(User::class, 'followers', 'follower_id', 'leader_id');
}
```

```
follower model protected $fillable=[

     "follower_id",
     "leader_id",
     
     
    ];
```

```
Controller    public function followCount( int $id)
    {
        $user = User::find($id); 
         
    $user->followers()->attach(auth()->user()->id);
   

    return redirect()->back()->with('success', 'Successfully followed the user.');
     
    }
```

````
   Schema::create('user', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('username');
            $table->string('email')->unique();
            $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
            $table->unsignedbigint("follower");
            $table->string('password');
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();
        });```
````

Comment: Yeah it would be appropriate as the thing you try to do is basically using a `withPivot(['pivotField'])` on the relationship and use `attach([$id => ['pivotField' => 'value']])` (https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#retrieving-intermediate-table-columns)

Comment: @RobBiermann I got an error say  Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'followers.follower' in 'field list'

Comment: Can you show the code in your question that you are trying? I think it might be a simple issue.

Comment: @RobBiermann So this is what I recently did ```$user->followers()->attach([$id => ['follower' => 'value']]);``` Here's my view and migration ```<div class="followCount">

<a href="{{route('follow', $profile->id)}}" id="Connect" class="btn btn-success">Connect</a>

<a href="{{route('unfollow', $profile->id)}}" id="Unconnect" class="btn btn-danger">Unconnect</a>
</div> ```

Comment: If you update the question, the code is more readable ;) Does your pivot table have a follower field?

Comment: I'd use `syncWithoutDetaching($id)` or `sync($id, false)` instead of `attach($id)`  to avoid getting duplicates in the pivot table.

Comment: @RobBiermann I edit my question and add my migiration

Comment: I think the issue is not with the users table, but with the followers table( based on your comment `Unknown column 'followers.follower'` Is there a follower column in followers?

Comment: @RobBiermann No there is not

Comment: Is that not the field you want to fill? Maybe you need to make a migration to make the column? Then it should work

Comment: @RobBiermann So try that now it's saying SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'follower' doesn't have a default value

Comment: @RobBiermann https://imgur.com/a/bpAhc7z Is there a way to chat privately

Comment: You havent set a default value for your column and are not passing a variable. Either define its default value or provide it in the attach/sync :)